# How Passing data between components in React?

Tags: reactjs

The question is why the error occurs?

Type '{ setSearchResultProps: (result: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}>'.
Property 'setSearchResultProps' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}>'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchResults from './SearchResults';

class ParentComponent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchResult: null,
    };
  }

  setSearchResult = (result: any) => {
         console.log('test setSearchResult ');
    this.setState({ searchResult: result });

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       
        <SearchResults setSearchResultProps={this.setSearchResult} />
   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface SearchResultsProps {
  setSearchResultProps: (result: any) => void;
}

class SearchResults extends Component<SearchResultsProps> {
 
  someFunction = () => {
    this.props.setSearchResultProps();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* SearchResults */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

I need to get data from one component and pass it to another component

Comment: I couldn't spot the error you mentioned in this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-gates-fd3hhk?file=/src/App.tsx

It might be a quirk in your `tsconfig`. If the project isn't too complex, sticking to plain JavaScript could save you some headaches. And when it comes to sharing data between components, use state management like: https://zustand-demo.pmnd.rs/

Comment: yes, maybe there is a problem with the ts I'll try to solve it